# background color change on mouse leave bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a navigation menu using Bootstrap 3 navbar. But It has a small issue:
When mouse moves over a menu item it perfectly change its color to dark green. But when I leave the menu, it does not directly changes its color to light-green. It quickly changes to gray(default) color and then turn to light green.

Below is a screen of my navigation bar:

[image]

```
.navbar-default{
    background-color: #4ec67f;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

li.active{
    background: #34b586 !important;
}

li > a:focus{
    background: #34b586 !important;
}

li:hover > a{
    background: #34b586 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

li > a:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background: #34b586 !important;
}
```

How to avoid this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quite hard task to debug an...image

Comment: You'll have to add some code to this post.

Comment: check in dom inspector if ondrop down any class is given to `li` with that you can add the hover styles to that class

Comment: Could you create an online demo..?

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic setup, and is all you need. It looks like your issue is that you're not setting a color on your anchor tags by default. Also, no need to set a focus style, just deal with the hover event.

http://jsfiddle.net/6uhbh3su/4/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li a:hover{

    background: red;
    color: white;
}
a{
    background: black;
    color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i want. when i apply background color to element <a> then it is visible also at the default state.

Comment: @solidshadow So just add that color in, instead of `black` ?